# Crasters sons in Game of Thrones, who raises them before they turn into White Walkers (if they do)?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Craster's sons being given as sacrifice is one that's really bothering me, because Craster gives them up as new born babies. So I've been wondering when they're changed to White Walkers. (I assume that's what happens, because I'm yet to read the books.)

Are they raised as humans till they're older and stronger by White Walkers? Or do White Walker babies age?

Comment: FWIW this is one of the few occasions where the show has more information than the books but we don’t know if things will be the same in the books. In the books it is only heavily implied that Craster’s sons are taken and turned into the Others by the Others.

Comment: The duplicate has a lot of answers and diluted information so I’m just going to shamelessly plug [my own answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/170090/58193) because it is actually sourced.

Comment: So basically nobody really knows yet

Comment: I only made this account to ask this question btw, so why bother editing the whole comment, I'm only trying to get some answers to my question

Answer (score 1):

In *Game of Thrones* S04E04 it is clearly shown that a White Walker is converting a baby into one of them. Adding video clip for your reference:

Comment: Yep, that's the scene I wrote about.  The clip also demonstrates that there are no Walker manicurists.

Comment: But the night king as an example has been around for thousands of years. So even if white walkers do age surely the babies aging is relevant to that

Comment: @Sarah neither show nor novels tell exactly how White Walkers age.

Answer (score -1):

In the TV show there's a baby taken and converted a few minutes later.  I assume they then grow into adult White Walkers.  Unless the White Walker babies have freezing diarrhea squirt powers that get revealed in the next book, in which case they may just keep them as weaponized White Walker infantry.

Comment: I’ve downvoted this because the diarrhoea commentary is wholey unnescassary and the part about _”a few minutes later”_ is just completely wrong.